# Change mov to set constant 0

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, ida

This is an instruction of executable:

```
mov dword_1006530C, esi -> 89 35 0C 53 06 10
```

How to change hex to move zeros to address?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: You mean write the value zero as a 32-bit bit poke to the absolute address 0x1006530C? If so then you will need some additional context about the surrounding code as there is insufficient code space to patch out the present instruction in-place. Incidentally, is the address constant or will you need to preserve a relocation record within an on-disk executable to be patched?

Comment: Final goal is to patch executable file. I am new in this area but my guess would be that I can change just bytes that belong to this instruction. Maybe I can check registers and see if there is one with 0 value at that execution point and change esi to that one? That would be a bit risky but if there is no easy solution that could work?

Comment: What would be HEX for mov dword_1006530C, edi ?

Comment: If you have a register with a zero value at hand, this would be a one-byte-change (second byte of instruction).

Comment: For esi - 35 and what is for edi? I can't find info on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not enough room to write an instructions sequence that writes zero to that address.
The address alone, encoded as an immediate, will takes four bytes. Leaving just two bytes for: a) saving a register b) zeroing it c) performing the store d) restoring the register.

If it happens that you have a zero in some other register you can change the instruction into

```
mov DWORD [1006530ch], <reg>
```

You can use [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) to quickly find out the machine code of such code: just write the code in a file, add `BITS 32` at the beginning.
Assemble it and inspect the output file with an hex editor.
For example `mov DWORD [1006530ch], edi` is `89 3D 0C 53 06 10`.

If you don't have a zero ready, the only solution is to replace the instruction with a `jmp` to a free spot in the text section (there is always a free spot) where you can paste your machine code and at the end jump back into the original program flow.

Comment: It would be shorter (but still not short enough) to use `mov r/m32, imm32`, instead of saving/restoring a register and zeroing it.  But yes, the conclusion is correct: if you don't have a zero in a reg, you can't do it in-place.